# How to find out which get and post request called in same function handler?

Tags: node.js, total.js

According to this example:

```
ROUTE('GET /api/users/', action);
ROUTE('POST /api/users/', action);
```

in the body of function `action` how we can find out get or post request has been called so that write appropriate code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might pass a function that *calls* `action` with another argument that indicates which method was used:

```
ROUTE('GET /api/users/', function(...args) { action.call(this, 'GET', ...args) });
ROUTE('POST /api/users/', function(...args) { action.call(this, 'POST', ...args) });
```

With this, the first argument passed to `action` will be the method used, and the rest of the arguments will be the ones that the `ROUTE` callback would receive normally.

Comment: It doesn't work! when i want to access `req` body from `this` object according to total.js docs, this object get empty and in another word i think write function in this way change the behavior.

Comment: If the calling context is important, then just change from an arrow function to a standard function, see edit

Comment: oh, and use `.call` too

Comment: it's correct, thanks! and we don't need the `...args`, passing `this` is enough.